# RxJava: return a cached value synchronously/immediately

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I'm looking to see if there's a way to return a cached value synchronously from an Observable that may otherwise take a long time to emit. Of course, if it needs to do its io/computation, then that should do it on the computation thread, but if it's already done it before, then that should be synchronous and avoid jumping back and forth between threads. Below is some example code of what I mean:

```
public void bind(ItemViewHolder holder) {
    getCalculationObservable()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(value -> {
                    holder.showValue(value); // This will happen after bind has finished
                }
            });
}

public Observable<Integer> getCalculationObservable() {
    if (mObservable == null) {

        mObservable = Observable.fromCallable(this::calculate)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .cache();

    }
    return mObservable;
}

public int calculate() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return mValue * 1000;
}
```

Edit: to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
void onRunSchedulerExampleButtonClicked() throws InterruptedException {


    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable
            .fromCallable(this::calculate)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .cache();

    observable
            .doOnNext(value -> {
                Log.e("log", "first onNext()");
            })
            .test().await();

    observable
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(value -> {
                Log.e("log", "second onNext()");
            })
            .test().await();

    Log.e("log", "this is first.");

}
```

Results:

```
E/log: onClick
E/log: first onNext()
E/log: this is first.
E/log: second onNext()
```

To further illustrate the point, if you add an await() on the second onNext chain, you'll never finish because it's going to await on something that's queued up in the same thread that you're blocking in.

Comment: Use `BehaviourSubject` for that: subscribe clients to subject, and make your observable push items into this subject internally. Thats how you can have execution on background thread and emission (of both cached/new value on main thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

When applying `observeOn` with `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` scheduler, downstream events get posted into `MessageQueue` by using `postDelayed` internally. That's why the code, that's located after the second Observable, executes *before* that Observable completes (or freezes if we use `test().await()`). A possible solution is to use `Subjects` as a proxy between your data source and subscribers. Check this article for more info - [Keep Your Main Thread Synchronous](http://blog.bradcampbell.nz/keep-your-main-thread-synchronous).

Also useful articles:

- [A journey on the Android Main Thread — Lifecycle bits](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/a-journey-on-the-android-main-thread-lifecycle-bits-d916bc1ee6b2)
- [RxJava and a synchronous main thread](http://helw.net/2016/07/24/rxjava-and-a-synchronous-main-thread/)

---

**Explanation why `cache` doesn't switch threads:**

Your `Observable` already returns cached value synchronously because `cache` doesn't subscribe to the whole upstream for every subscriber (thus in your case it doesn't switch threads). It does it once and then just remembers the sequence of items. For every new subscriber, `cache` just replays it.

---

**Example:**
(written in *Kotlin*)

```
//here is the same logic as yours
private var observable: Observable<Int>? = null
    get() {
        if(field==null)
            field = Observable.fromCallable {
                System.out.println("callable: execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                return@fromCallable 1000
            }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .doOnNext     { System.out.println("cached Observable: before cache() - doOnNext execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
                    .doOnComplete { System.out.println("cached Observable: before cache() - doOnComplete execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
                    .cache()
                    .doOnNext     { System.out.println("cached Observable: after cache() - doOnNext execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
                    .doOnComplete { System.out.println("cached Observable: after cache() - doOnComplete execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }

        return field
    }

@Test
fun test() {
    observable!!
            .doOnSubscribe { System.out.println("first get: doOnSubscribe execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
            .doOnNext      { System.out.println("first get: doOnNext execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
            .doOnComplete  { System.out.println("first get: doOnComplete execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
            .test()
            .await()

    System.out.println("---------- first get executed ------------")

    observable!!
            .doOnSubscribe { System.out.println("second get: doOnSubscribe execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
            .doOnNext      { System.out.println("second get: doOnNext execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
            .doOnComplete  { System.out.println("second get: doOnComplete execution thread - ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
            .subscribe()
}
```

**Output:**

```
first get: doOnSubscribe execution thread - main
callable: body execution thread - RxComputationThreadPool-1
cached Observable: before cache() - doOnNext execution thread - RxComputationThreadPool-1
cached Observable: after cache() - doOnNext execution thread - RxComputationThreadPool-1
first get: doOnNext execution thread - RxComputationThreadPool-1
cached Observable: before cache() - doOnComplete execution thread - RxComputationThreadPool-1
cached Observable: after cache() - doOnComplete execution thread - RxComputationThreadPool-1
first get: doOnComplete execution thread - RxComputationThreadPool-1
---------- first get executed ------------
second get: doOnSubscribe execution thread - main
cached Observable: after cache() - doOnNext execution thread - main
second get: doOnNext execution thread - main
cached Observable: after cache() - doOnComplete execution thread - main
second get: doOnComplete execution thread - main
```

As you can see, when there is cached value, threads doesn't get switched.

P.S. I assume that you use RxJava2.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. While the second get does appear on the main thread, it does not return synchronously. Instead, it gets queued on the looper and executes later. This can be easily verified by a log after the second get (of course, can't use await/test here).

Comment: Notably, a big difference is that your observable doesn't do observesOn, which seems to force this queuing. The observesOn(mainThread) is basically a requirement, since can't touch views off of main thread and all.

Comment: I've omitted observeOn deliberately to show that thread doesn't switch when there is cached value. I've edited answer adding a lot of logging calls. And still - when there is the second get - Computation Scheduler doesn't get involved.

Comment: @DavidLiu, why do you think that? if that's was the case, then Test would end before printing all Observable logs

Comment: The omitting of observeOn is exactly the reason why you're not encountering the problem I'm talking about. Additionally, thread switching is not the problem I'm talking about. Like I've said, it's the queuing of the message onto the looper and executing it on the next pass.

Comment: @yosriz added example code that shows exactly what happens.

Comment: I finally got it. The problem you are trying to solve is - when applying `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` events get posted into `MessageQueue` by using `postDelayed` internally. That's why the code, that's located after the second Observable, executes _before_ that Observable completes (or freezes if we use `test().await()`). Possible solution described in this article - http://blog.bradcampbell.nz/keep-your-main-thread-synchronous

Comment: Ah thank you. I was trying to play with the Subject solution, but couldn't figure out where to correctly put the subscribeOn/observeOn to fix it. This works great! If you could post it as another answer or edit into this one, I'll accept that.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Thank you for the interesting question.